# Define specific color for each data in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hello i have the following question. Is there a way to set ONE color for each Data... here is the code .

**HTML with Chart**

```
    <canvas 
     baseChart height="100"
            [datasets]="lineChartData"
            [options]="lineChartOptions"
            [colors]="lineChartColors"
            [legend]="lineChartLegend"
            [chartType]="lineChartType"
      ></canvas>

</div>
<button 
type="button"
class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=""
(click)="ventanaSincro()">Actualizar Rx1</button> <br>
</div>
```

**Initialize chart in component**

```
public lineChartData:any[] =  [
    { label: 'IG',data : [{x: this.intGua ,y: 60,}, {x: this.intGua,y: 0}], borderDash : [ 60 , 5]},


];
public chart_visible: boolean = true

public  lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    animation: false,
    scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom'
            }]
        }
  };
public lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(33,150,243,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(76,175,80,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(244,67,54,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(103,58,183,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,152,0,0.8)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(96,125,139,0.8)'
    }    
  ];

  public lineChartLegend: boolean = true;
  public lineChartType: string = 'scatter';
  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

**Method that update the chart data**

```
     ventanaSincro() {
             this.intGua =  this._moduladorService.obtenerIntGua();
             this.Deltas = this._markerService.getDeltasRx1();
             var DeltaPrueba : any = [ this.Deltas[0], this.Deltas[1], this.Deltas[2], this.Deltas[3]];
             var DeltaCR : any = [ this.Deltas[4], this.Deltas[5], this.Deltas[6], this.Deltas[7]];
             var DistanciaRx1 = this._markerService.getDistanacias();
            console.log("aca",DeltaPrueba);




                let temp = [{  label: 'Tx1',data : [{x: this.Deltas[0],y: DistanciaRx1[0],}, {x: this.Deltas[0],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx2',data : [{x: this.Deltas[1],y: DistanciaRx1[1]}, {x: this.Deltas[1],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx3',data : [{x: this.Deltas[2],y: DistanciaRx1[2]}, {x: this.Deltas[2],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx4',data : [{x: this.Deltas[3],y: DistanciaRx1[3]}, {x: this.Deltas[3],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx1CR',data : [{x: this.Deltas[4],y: DistanciaRx1[4]}, {x: this.Deltas[4],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx2CR',data : [{x: this.Deltas[5],y: DistanciaRx1[5]}, {x: this.Deltas[5],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx3CR',data : [{x: this.Deltas[6],y: DistanciaRx1[6]}, {x: this.Deltas[6],y: 0}]},
                { label: 'Tx4CR',data : [{x: this.Deltas[7],y: DistanciaRx1[7]}, {x: this.Deltas[7],y: 0}]},
                ]


            this.chart_visible = false
            let lineChartData:any[] =  Object.assign([],[
                 { label: 'IG',data : [{x: this.intGua ,y: 60,}, {x: this.intGua,y: 0}], borderDash : [ 60 , 5]},


                ]);
            console.log('testing ---')

            for (let i=0; i<=3; i++){
                let val = this['tra'+i];
                console.log(val)
                if (val){
                    lineChartData.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }
            if(this.obst && this.tra0){
                lineChartData.push(temp[4]);
            }    
            if(this.obst && this.tra1){
                lineChartData.push(temp[5]);
            }    
            if(this.obst && this.tra2){
                lineChartData.push(temp[6]);
            }    
            if(this.obst && this.tra3){
                lineChartData.push(temp[7]);
            }    
            this.lineChartData = Object.assign([],lineChartData)
            this.lineChartOptions = Object.assign({}, this.lineChartOptions)
            console.log(lineChartData)
            setTimeout(()=>{
                this.chart_visible = true
            })




  }
```

I need for example for data of label IG : blue.
for data of label Tx1 : red.
for data of label Tx2 : greeen .

And so on, but the thing is that they need to have only one constant color for each label with its data.

Thanks !

Comment: you mean different color for each data-points?

Comment: @ℊααnd yes ! and if u see the code i only have 2 points so it draw 1 line for each label..

Comment: something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmkXh.png) ?

Comment: no, only one color for a label with its data, so DST 1 should always be blue, and DST always be pink... the line and dots... how can i make the colors constant for each label..

Comment: like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh9Gz.png) then?

Comment: @ℊααnd yes! but, make sure that it will always be blue for DST1, beacuse if u dont enter data for DST1 blue will be assigned to DST2.

Comment: obviously, this is expected. if you don't set data for DST1 then DST2 will become the first dataset, thus the color will apply which was set for DST1. you may perhaps add an empty object to the dataset array if there is no data. remember that lengths of datasets and colors array must be the same.